# clear the old values from textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a way to clear the old values from text box when I refresh the page using jquery.
I tried this code but it didn't work.

```
$('#flip_list_search').value = "";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#flip_list_search").val('');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$('#flip_list_search').val('');
```

or

```
$('#flip_list_search')[0].value ='';
```

---

`.value` works with native DOM Object `$('#flip_list_search')` is jQuery Object

`$('#flip_list_search')[0]` to get first native DOM Object

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input#flip_list_search","#Your_form_Id").val('');
```

You can use this. It will be more help to detect your element. Here **#Your_form_Id** is the id that contains your text box. jQuery search your text box only the **#Your_form_Id** portion in lieu of whole DOM.

Answer (score 1):

this will work for you:

```
$('#flip_list_search').val("");
```